# Replacing numbers in a string with Applescript and BBEdit

Tags: replace, find, applescript, bbedit

I am a total beginner and have written a few little scripts that feed use Applescript to feed BBEdit a list of find and replace fields, primarily for formatting. I.e. convert  to tag1, tag2, etc.

I'm trying to use the same method to replace some numbers so find 9 replace with 1. It only works if the number has a space either side. I.e. tag9 9, is replaced with tag9 1. I wondered if someone could tell me why?

Here is my script:

```
set line1replaceList to {{"0", "1"}, {"9", "1"}, {"8", "1"}, {"7", "1"}, {"6", "1"}, {"5", "1"}, {"4", "1"}, {"3", "1"}, {"2", "1"}}

tell application "BBEdit"
    tell window 1
        repeat with thePair in line1replaceList
            replace (item 1 of thePair) using (item 2 of thePair) options {starting at top:true, case sensitive:false, match words:true, search mode:grep}
            # Check the "Search Options" in TextWrangler's scipting dictionary!
        end repeat
    end tell

end tell
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Tom

Comment: You don't need to use _BBEdit_ for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the "match words" part and it should work. In fact, you don't need the grep part, either.

So the line would be:

`replace (item 1 of thePair) using (item 2 of thePair) options {starting at top:true, case sensitive:false}`

Comment: Awesome, that did exactly what I wanted! Thank you :-)